# Testflight Ad-hoc distribution does not work if the GoogleMaps.bundle is added to the apps resources

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, resources, testflight

I started to develop an iOS application that needs to use the Google Maps SDK. I followed the steps on the Google web page and added it successfully to the project. The problem is that now my testers cannot download the app via TestFlight, which is distributed with Ad-hoc provision profile and signing. There is an error at the last stage of the progress bar "Unable to download the application right now". -> Done, Retry. I do not know the exact message as it is not English for me. But the message is such small, and the meaning is correct.

The app runs well on the ios simulator, and also on my iphone device, with the working map display as well.

I went through the process now 4 times and finally I was able to identify which step causes this: the step to add the googleMaps.bundle to my resources inside the app. So if I remove the bundle from the list of Frameworks (keep the SDK itself) then the app is compilable, downloadable via TestFlight. If I put it back, it is not. Of course I have runtime crash if the bundle is missing, so I cannot do that.

When i open the console log in the Organizer it tell this:

```
Nov 26 09:42:17 -iPhone-keszuleke installd[1030] <Error>: 0x2ffe6000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app hu.vivify.muzeumtura
Nov 26 09:42:18 -iPhone-keszuleke installd[1030] <Error>: Nov 26 09:42:18  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Nov 26 09:42:18 -iPhone-keszuleke installd[1030] <Error>: 0x2ffe6000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.sFC3ox/foo_extracted/Payload/muzeumtura.app/muzeumtura: 0xe8008017
Nov 26 09:42:18 -iPhone-keszuleke installd[1030] <Error>: 0x2ffe6000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.sFC3ox/foo_extracted/Payload/muzeumtura.app
Nov 26 09:42:18 -iPhone-keszuleke itunesstored[72] <Error>: 0x1698000 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
Nov 26 09:42:18 -iPhone-keszuleke installd[1030] <Error>: 0x2ffe6000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Nov 26 09:42:18 -iPhone-keszuleke installd[1030] <Error>: 0x2ffe6000 handle_install: API failed
```

Then after a few more hours I have found the advice of trying the terminal for the codesign command. This gives a lot of missing resources in the googleMaps.bundle:

```
Desktop/Payload/muzeumtura.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
In architecture: armv7
resource missing: /Users/daz/Desktop/Payload/muzeumtura.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/._polyline_colors_texture.png
resource missing: /Users/daz/Desktop/Payload/muzeumtura.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/nl.lproj/._GMSCore.strings
resource missing: /Users/daz/Desktop/Payload/muzeumtura.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/._tr.lproj
resource missing: /Users/daz/Desktop/Payload/muzeumtura.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/de.lproj/._GMSCore.strings
resource missing: /Users/daz/Desktop/Payload/muzeumtura.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/el.lproj/._GMSCore.strings
resource missing: /Users/daz/Desktop/Payload/muzeumtura.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/._ru.lproj
resource missing: /Users/daz/Desktop/Payload/muzeumtura.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/._ms.lproj
```

... and so on. It is strange that these files listed are all hidden (starting with ._) I do not know it this has any connection to the Testflight problem, or whether this issue in the terminal is critical or not (this is the first time to use the codesign command for me). But I guess so. Please help me find this out, as it must be something trivial, because the app is very simple and I am sure I am not the only one on this planet who wants to integrate the googleMaps SDK into the ios app.

Some more info:
I have XCode 5.0, OSX 10.8.4
I have enabled to show hidden files in Finder
I want to build for armv7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that was my fault. When the GoogleMaps.bundle was added to the project by the drag-n-drop, the bundle was on a disk with exFAT partition table! Who would have thought that this can be a reason? I am sad because one and half day of my life and the project had gone. But I am happy that now it works. Good advice: do not use exFAT for iPhone development!

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with testflight, sometimes happened with me too. This is not particularly related with google maps, try other methods

[Distribute ipa to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137569/distribute-ipa-to-client/20137643?noredirect=1#comment30013382_20137643)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried Diawi but the symptom is the same. When the app is downloaded, at the end the error message appears. Same as with testflight. I have removed my provisioning profile from settings, the reinstall from diawi, but still the same...

Comment: I have deleted all my profiles and then regeneretaed them. I build the  app in release for an adhoc distribution, then at the distribution section I sign it with the same provisioning profile. I really have a doubt in myself at this point ... :(